# html5mode gives 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to remove the hashtag from the URL in my AngularJS app. I'm using Web API 2.0 to retrieve some data. This is what I've done:

In my app.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/products", {
                templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html"
            })
            .when("/products/:id", {
                templateUrl: "app/products/productInfoView.html" 
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/products" });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I've also added `<base href="/">` to my **index.html**.

It works fine when I go to `http://localhost:49767/` and navigate from there using links.

For example, clicking a product takes me to `http://localhost:49767/products/5` and loads the information just fine. However, if I go directly to `http://localhost:49767/products` or directly to a specific product I get 404 not found error from IIS.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure your server to work with html5mode.

**ASP.Net C# Rewrites**

In Global.asax

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/default.aspx";

protected void Application_BeginRequest( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
    if ( !System.IO.File.Exists( Context.Server.MapPath( url ) ) )
        Context.RewritePath( ROOT_DOCUMENT );
}
```

See [this link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) for more information

Comment: I'm using the WEB API project with angularjs. After adding this, my service calls are not working. Any idea on the error ? I was also trying to remove this '#' from the urls.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, my way is :

delete `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

and `<a href="#/products/1">1</a><a href="#/products/2">2</a>`