# Angular.js route -- how to remove html filename from the route

Tags: angularjs

OK, so I am an Angular.js newbie and I am working on creating some rudimentary routing. I have the following definition for my routing:

```
JBenchApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/calendar', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/dashboard'
        });
  }]);
```

When I load the page http://localhost:53465/default.html what I get is

```
http://localhost:53465/default.html#/dashboard
```

How can I make this show up as

```
http://localhost:53465/dashboard
```

Comment: what happens when you go to http://localhost:53465/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routes that you have defined are the text that appear after the hashbang in the URL - hashbang because you do not seemed to have set HTML5 mode to true.

Thus, when you load the page `http://localhost:53465/default.html`, AngularJS will attempt to load the route `http://localhost:53465/default.html/#!/` where the route is `/` - the text that appears after the hashbang(#!).

Look at your routes. There is no route handler for `/`. Thus, the `otherwise()` function is executed which simply redirects to the route `/dashboard`. Thus, the final URL is `http://localhost:53465/default.html/#!/dashboard`

If you want to load the URL as `http://localhost:53465/dashboard` then simply provide the above URL as it is. You don't have to specify default.html as the route handler takes care of loading the relevant HTML file (based on the `templateUrl` property of the route handler object)

Comment: OK, so I enabled html5Mode and added $locationProvider to the routes configuration. I also added a <base href="/"> tag to the head of my index.html page. Now when i start the project I am sent directly to the http://localhost:53465/dashboard but if I change that to be http://localhost:53465/calendar I get a 404 error.

Comment: This article fixed my 404 errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424507/html5mode-gives-404-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Rename `default.html` to `index.html` then you'll be able to navigate to `http://localhost:53465/#/dashboard`.

Comment: I just tried that. Upon loading the site I see http://localhost:53465/index.html#/dashboard and when I remove the index.html I am told the page doesn't exist